# Gridview broke - Nothing Changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm creating an application in ASP.Net where team leaders can edit targets per hour for a specific item. I'm scheduled to present this project to multiple people today and I debugged the project to have a run through and practice my speech.

However, a problem arose. The code where I retrieve the values from the Gridview to be inserted into a database is broken.

The error message I recieve is:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in
> System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

The code I use to retrieve the values is:

```
 string contractName = gvShowData.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gvShowData.Rows[e.RowIndex];
 TextBox txtContractName = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("Contract");
 string txtCName = ((TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtModel = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtProcess = ((TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH0 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH1 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH2 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[6].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH3 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[7].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH4 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[8].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH5 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[9].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH6 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[10].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH7 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[11].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH8 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[12].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH9 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[13].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH10 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[14].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH11 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[15].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH12 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[16].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH13 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[17].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH14 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[18].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH15 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[19].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH16 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[20].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH17 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[21].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH18 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[22].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH19 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[23].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH20 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[24].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH21 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[25].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH22 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[26].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH23 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[27].Controls[0]).Text;
```

Whole Update statement (with database connection string and table names removed).

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);

string contractName = gvShowData.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gvShowData.Rows[e.RowIndex];
TextBox txtContractName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Contract");
//string txtCName = row.Cells[1].Text;
//string txtModel = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtProcess = ((TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH0 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH1 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH2 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[6].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH3 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[7].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH4 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[8].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH5 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[9].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH6 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[10].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH7 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[11].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH8 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[12].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH9 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[13].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH10 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[14].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH11 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[15].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH12 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[16].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH13 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[17].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH14 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[18].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH15 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[19].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH16 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[20].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH17 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[21].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH18 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[22].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH19 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[23].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH20 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[24].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH21 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[25].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH22 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[26].Controls[0]).Text;
//string txtH23 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[27].Controls[0]).Text;

var list = new List<string>();

foreach(var cell in row.Cells)
{
    list.Add((cell.Controls[0] as TextBox).Text);
}


gvShowData.EditIndex = -1;
con.Open();

DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";

string commandString = "INSERT INTO dms (Contract, Line, Process, H0,H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,H7,H8,H9,H10,H11,H12,H13,H14,H15,H16,H17,H18,H19,H20,H21,H22,H23,timestamp,username) VALUES('" + txtCName + "','" + txtModel + "','" + txtProcess + "','" + txtH0 + "','" + txtH1 + "','" + txtH2 + "','" + txtH3 + "','" + txtH4 + "','" + txtH5 + "','" + txtH6 + "','" + txtH7 + "','" + txtH8 + "','" + txtH9 + "','" + txtH10 + "','" + txtH11 + "','" + txtH12 + "','" + txtH13 + "','" + txtH14 + "','" + txtH15 + "','" + txtH16 + "','" + txtH17 + "','" + txtH18 + "','" + txtH19 + "','" + txtH20 + "','" + txtH21 + "','" + txtH22 + "','" + txtH23 + "','" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString(format) + "','" + User.Identity.Name.ToString() + "')";

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(commandString, con);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
BindGridView();
```

Comment: Don't use `Cell.FindControl` but `Row.FindControl`. The `NamingContainer` of any control in an Itemtemplate is the `GridViewRow` not the cell. That makes it much more readable and less error-prone.

Comment: As the error suggest `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` may be there ain't any cell at index **27** but still you are trying to access it in databound event. Please follow @TimSchmelter approach.

Comment: One of the many reasons I love programming is that `an error has arisen, but nothing changed` is never true. There's always a change of some sort if there's a change in behaviour or path of execution. My comment may seem non-constructive - but take it as advice to be totally open minded about things that have possibly introduced errors.

Comment: I'd also advise (after your presentation) that you get this on code review and spend some time considering alternative approaches. The repetitiveness of these variable declaration and instantiations are crying out for a loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Do you mean  TextBox txtContractName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Contract"); or changing all the strings to find a control?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ No source code was changed. The only change I made was opening the project and hitting f5 for a debug. I also agree the code isn't very nice and it'd be changed closer to a release. This is a really early concept to remove a time consuming task of manually assigning targets in a db using Excel and ETL scripts. My plan is to tidy all the code up and introduce better standards and practices that weren't essentially needing for this release.

Comment: @Paul - maybe the code didn't change - maybe it was something else that constructs the gridview - a data source perhaps? Either way, your code is making explicit assumptions about what it expects from the gridview. That's not necessarily a terrible idea - but you're not catering for errors correctly.

Comment: @Paul: yes, that's what i've meant. We need to see your aspx code to see how you get the other controls.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've edited OP to include the full Update code.

Comment: @Paul: always use sql parameters instead of string concatenation to prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

You could refactor this:

```
 string txtCName = ((TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtModel = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtProcess = ((TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH0 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH1 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH2 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[6].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH3 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[7].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH4 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[8].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH5 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[9].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH6 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[10].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH7 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[11].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH8 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[12].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH9 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[13].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH10 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[14].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH11 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[15].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH12 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[16].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH13 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[17].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH14 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[18].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH15 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[19].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH16 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[20].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH17 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[21].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH18 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[22].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH19 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[23].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH20 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[24].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH21 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[25].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH22 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[26].Controls[0]).Text;
 string txtH23 = ((TextBox)row.Cells[27].Controls[0]).Text;
```

To read:

```
var list = new List<string>();

foreach(TableCell cell in row.Cells)
   list.Add((cell.Controls[0] as TextBox).Text);
```

How you then retrieve the values separately would change a bit. But since your variable names appear to be following a strict sequence anyway I don't see it being a problem fetching the list elements by index.

For example instead of `myControl.Text = txtH0;` it would now be `myControl.Text = list[0];` How you get '0' is upto you, it's usually part of a loop.

Some may say this doesn't answer the question and is rather a code review - but it *does* also solve the problem - there'll now be no exception.

NOTE: Be careful with the assumption that your control is definitely there and is definitely a `TextBox`

Comment: This code gives > Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Controls' and no extension method 'Controls' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ARCManualUpdates A:\DEVELOPMENT\arc_manual_updates_v3\ARCManualUpdates\ARCManualUpdates\Default.aspx.cs 254

Comment: I think `TableCell` in the shortened code should really be `GridViewCell` - or similar.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't get round to testing this as I don't have an IDE in front of me. Feel free to edit.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Ah sorry. I was also aircoding (and thinking of Telerik). It looks fine. But you *are* missing a new in `var list = List<string>();` - unfortunately too few characters for me to edit.

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix - well caught!!

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of this with a rip of @JayMee answer.

The new code for the update is:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        string contractName = gvShowData.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gvShowData.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        TextBox txtContractName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Contract");
        string txtCName = row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
        string txtModel = row.Cells[2].Text.ToString();
        string txtProcess = row.Cells[3].Text.ToString();

        var list = new List<string>();

        for(int cell = 4; cell < 28; cell++)
        {
            list.Add((row.Cells[cell].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text.ToString());
        }

        gvShowData.EditIndex = -1;
        con.Open();

        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";

        string commandString = "INSERT INTO dms (Contract, Line, Process, H0,H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,H7,H8,H9,H10,H11,H12,H13,H14,H15,H16,H17,H18,H19,H20,H21,H22,H23,timestamp,username) VALUES('" + txtCName + "','" + txtModel + "','" + txtProcess + "','" + list[0] + "','" + list[1] + "','" + list[2] + "','" + list[3] + "','" + list[4] + "','" + list[5] + "','" + list[6] + "','" + list[7] + "','" + list[8] + "','" + list[9] + "','" + list[10] + "','" + list[11] + "','" + list[12] + "','" + list[13] + "','" + list[14] + "','" + list[15] + "','" + list[16] + "','" + list[17] + "','" + list[18] + "','" + list[19] + "','" + list[20] + "','" + list[21] + "','" + list[22] + "','" + list[23] + "','" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString(format) + "','" + User.Identity.Name.ToString() + "')";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(commandString, con);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        BindGridView();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd explicitly set `28` here, but rather use `Cells.Count/Cells.Length` (not sure which)

Comment: Also, I see another reason for a loop there (the concatenation of the list items). The minute you start repeating yourself - you normally have a use for a loop of some sort. In fact, you could even use `join`: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-join

Comment: You're right - I could use string.join here on the update statement and build the query from there. I'll have a look into this after my presentation.